# Echo command + variable expansion before exec

Tags: linux, bash

How to echo the actual command WITH variables expanded (replaced by their values) before the execution? There are similar questions in SO where the majority of answers advised to use set -x or set -v. Somehow this doesn't work in my case. Hope you can help to pinpoint the error:

Content of **myTest.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -v # enable echo command before execution

myTable="TEST_COL890_TABLE"
WhereClause="coL2 > 0"

grep -Eio Col[0-9]+ <<- EOF
  SELECT * FROM $myTable
  GROUP BY Col1
  WHERE $WhereClause
  ORDER BY Col3
EOF

set +v # disable echo command before execution
```

Executed by:

```
$ chmod 744 ./myTest.sh
$ sh ./myTest.sh
```

Console Output (notice variables are NOT expanded)

> myTable=TEST_COL890_TABLE
>   + myTable=TEST_COL890_TABLE
>   WhereClause="coL2 > 0"
>   + WhereClause='coL2 > 0'
>   
>   grep -Eio Col[0-9]+ <<- EOF
>     SELECT * FROM $myTable
>     GROUP BY Col1
>     WHERE $WhereClause
>     ORDER BY Col3
>   EOF
>   + grep -Eio 'Col[0-9]+'
>   COL890
>   Col1
>   coL2
>   Col3
>
> set +vx # disable echo command before execution
>   + set +vx

Expected screen output (variables $myTable and $WhereClause substituted by their values)

> myTable=TEST_COL890_TABLE
>   WhereClause="coL2 > 0"
>
> grep -Eio Col[0-9]+ <<- EOF
>     SELECT * FROM TEST_COL890_TABLE
>     GROUP BY Col1
>     WHERE coL2 > 0
>     ORDER BY Col3
>   EOF
>   + grep -Eio 'Col[0-9]+'
>   COL890
>   Col1
>   coL2
>   Col3

Comment: It doesn't work because it's not part of the actual command, it's part of the redirection, the command is just `grep -Eio Col[0-9]+`. Try assigning the value to a variable before feeding it into `grep`, it will probably show the expansion that way.

Comment: @Polymerase: Please note that your shebang line is `#!/bin/sh`, but if you're really talking about _Bash_, it should be `#!/bin/bash` (or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`)

Comment: @mklement0 my dev environment is bash. But the script will run on Redhat 6.4 with Korn shell. Would that be still OK if I follow your suggestion?

Comment: @Polymerase: As long as Bash is _installed_ on your target machines, you should use the Bash shebang line - that allows you to confidently use Bash features without worrying about cross-shell compatibility.

Comment: I agree with mklement0, targetting the specific shell which the code was prepared for is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *complement* [KurzedMetal's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236871/kurzedmetal):

**In case you still want the flexibility of a here-document** (not having to quote embedded double-quotes, the option of stripping leading tabs), try the following:

```
# Read input into variable $input via here-document
IFS= read -r -d '' input <<-EOF
  SELECT * FROM $myTable
  GROUP BY Col1
  WHERE $WhereClause
  ORDER BY Col3
EOF

# Turn on tracing
set -x

# Use `:`, a special builtin called the null utility whose sole purpose is
# to expand its arguments - and nothing else.
# With -x on, this will print the expanded value.
# If -x is off, expansions still occur, but without any visible or side effects.
: "$input"

# Invoke the command - input provided via stdin (<<<) will NOT show.
grep -Eio 'Col[0-9]+' <<< "$input"

# Turn tracing back off
set +x
```

See also: the [POSIX spec for `:`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#colon), the null utility.

Comment: Oh cool, I like this solution better. Learnt about the "null utility" in the process.

Answer (score 3):

Bash documentation on `set -v`:

> Print shell input lines as they are read.

(the previous means it doesn't do expansion).

Bash documentation on `set -x`:

> Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select
>   commands, and arithmetic for commands and their arguments or
>   associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are
>   executed. The value of the PS4 variable is expanded and the resultant
>   value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments.

I guess `set -x` doesn't show redirected data, and you are only seeing just the unexpanded read line of the `set -v` output.

If you assign the text you are using in the `EOF` heredoc to a variable, and `set -x` will show you the expanded value correctly when doing the assignment.

So, change your code to this:

```
select="SELECT * FROM $myTable
GROUP BY Col1
WHERE $WhereClause
ORDER BY Col3"

grep -Eio 'Col[0-9]+' <<< "$select"
```

Comment: @mklement0 I usually just keep in mind not colliding popular Environment Variables, but I guess not using all-uppercase names is even better, seems like a good practice :P